# Xcode5 Storyboard Issue - UILabel position Designtime and Runtime

Tags: ios, iphone, objective-c, xcode, uiviewcontroller

How can i fix this Issue ?
The `UILabel` of my `UIViewController` has different positions during designtime (Storyboard) and runtime.
My App Runs in Landscape Orientation.

I've set the `UIViewController` also in Orientation Landscape but it doesn't matter.

**1. Storybord**

[image]

**2. Runtime**

[image]

How can i fix this.
I want to have the same postion in Runtime as in Storyboard

Thanks for your support

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In storyboard uncheck your Extend Edges `Under Top Bars` of your viewController,

[image]

Or

Check your autolayout  Constraints for that label.

Comment: Thank You, unchecking Under Top Bars solves the Issue.